# How to obtain arc length of this curve??

Tags: calculus, arc-length

In order to get the arc length we must have $r$ as a function of $\theta$.
But how can I find arc length of curve which is drawn between $r$ and $\theta$ if $r$ is an implicit function of $\theta$ like this:

\begin{align}
\theta = \frac{a\cdot \left( b - \sqrt{r^2 - rf+p^2} \right) }{r}
\end{align}

Where $f$ and $p$ are constants.

Comment: Welcome to MSE. It is in your best interest that you type your questions (using [MathJax](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference)) instead of posting links to pictures.

Comment: what is the $f$ and $p$ inside the square root? $r^2-rf+p^2$?

Comment: Everything expect r and theta is constants

Comment: @JoséCarlosSantos ok sir

Comment: You probably mean *explicit*.

Comment: @YvesDaoust, the above function is an implicit function of $\theta$. It would be called explicit if it was written as $r = f(\theta)$

Comment: @AvenDesta: wrong. You have $\theta$ as an explicit function of $r$. Implicit would be $f(r,\theta)=0$.

Answer (score 0):

Since $ds^2=dr^2+r^2d\theta^2$, when $\theta$ is given as a function of $r$ the arc length is$$\int ds=\int\sqrt{1+r^2(d\theta/dr)^2}\;dr.$$In this case,$$\begin{align}r\frac{d\theta}{dr}&=-\frac{a}{r}\left(b+\frac{fr/2-p^2}{\sqrt{r^2-fr+p^2}}\right)\\\implies\int ds&=\int\sqrt{1+\frac{a^2}{r^2}\left(b^2+\frac{(fr/2-p^2)^2}{r^2-fr+p^2}+\frac{b(fr-2p^2)}{\sqrt{r^2-fr+p^2}}\right)}\;dr.\end{align}$$However, I suspect you may need to evaluate such an arc length numerically.